# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, json

I am converting an array to json from php `json_encode()`. If I encode it for one array I can decode it, but when it is like this:`array('a'=>array(0=>array(),1=>array()))` it returns `{"a":[[],[]]}`

When I decode it I get the following error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

json source

the json is [here](http://pastebin.com/rLw4ABwS)

Comment: you try to echo the json_decode result.

Comment: always validate your json data using `http://jsonlint.com/`

Comment: json is fine thats not an issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use `true` as second parameter in `json_decode`

```
$arr = json_decode($your_array,true); // it will create array
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/0Dxxm8

Comment: any idea how to do it in json.parse ??

Comment: there is my json its returning valid http://json.parser.online.fr/ here but not parsing in neither php nor javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is valid json and working too
It is already a json so no need to parse this json

```
var json={};//copy json from http://pastebin.com/rLw4ABwS

console.log(json);
```

Test the code on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rRNSN/

Check in console it returns as an object means it is valid json,
If it will be a string then it needs to be parse using `JSON.parse()` or by `jquery.parseJSON()`.